# Android vs android-sdk-mac_86

Tags: android, sdk

Why have I got two Android directories on my Mac?

Both are under ~/Library.

One is `Android` (which contains a 9.4GB sdk folder) and the other is `android-sdk-mac_86` (which contains a 1.7GB `system-images` folder and a 1.7GB `add-ons` folder).

What's the difference and can I delete one of them?

Comment: Wild gaMy wild guess is that "system-images" is for x86 architecture system images.

Answer (score 1):

The first question is which of the SDKs you use from your IDE (Android Studio?). 
If it's not declared in your Android Studio preferences, it might be in a system variable (try `echo $ANDROID_HOME` from terminal)

My guess is that you're using the `android-sdk-mac_x86`, and you should keep that one. this looks like the latest official Stand-alone SDK, as written in the [developer site](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools):

> Unpack the ZIP file you've downloaded. By default, it's unpacked into
>   a directory named **android-sdk-mac_x86**. Move it to an appropriate
>   location on your machine, such as a "Development" directory in your
>   home directory.
>
> Make a note of the name and location of the SDK directory on your
>   system—you will need to refer to the SDK directory later when using
>   the SDK tools from the command line.

The folders you mentioned also fit what this SDK comes with.

If you are still not sure, you can rename one of them and see if everything still ticks.

I would personally delete both, and start with a fresh SDK that fits your current SDK packages, we usually carry junk from the past we don't actually need (http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html)

Comment: `echo $ANDROID_HOME` returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The Android directory contains Android studio and all the relevant files, while the other directory contains the stand alone SDK tools. You have the option to download either or both from their website.

You can delete both of them given you have the privileges.